# Calling GAS Script published as a Service from GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, service, google-apps-script

I have created a Google Apps Script doPost script that I have published as a Service, only available to myself (as described in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces#RunDecision, section "Publishing a Script as a Service").

I have now a URL like https://sites.google.com/a/macros/[google apps domain]/exec?service=[service key]

I want to call this service from a Google App Engine GWT application, but I don't know how to manage with authentication.

If selecting the "Allow anyone to invoke this service" then "Allow anonymous access", then I can call this service from AppEngine, but in my case, I absolutely need the authentication.

Do you have any idea how to handle it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to call this script from server to server and both of the endpoints are in your ownership, you could use a shared secret to do so, e.g.

Apps Script:

```
function doPost(e) {
   if(e.parameters.secret != 'mysecret') {
     return ContentService.createTextOutput("Nice try!");
   }
   // your code here
}
```

and transmit it with the request. If you only share your script with "Anyone having the link" that should provide reasonable security - make sure you never log that request nor include it in an error message however ;)